# OpenCV Как определить угол наклона стрелки правильно?

Tags: python, opencv

У меня есть код, который находит стрелку, обводит ее в квадрат, ищет начальную и конечную точку, проводит прямую между ними. Но при высчитывании градуса, через math.degrees градус высчитывается от 0 до 90 градусов и от -0 до -90[image: Как на картинке ниже я определил на ощупь]

Код вопроса:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass


font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow("Adjust")
cv2.createTrackbar("min", "Adjust", 110, 255, nothing)

def getcontours(vdo,th1):
    contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(vdo, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for ix, contour in enumerate(contours):
         area= cv2.contourArea(contour)

         if area>1000:
             cv2.drawContours(th1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
             peri=cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
             approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
             objcor=len(approx)
             x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)

Определение точек и угла:

             **if objcor ==7:
                 cv2.rectangle(th1,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (255,0,0),2)
                 startpoint= (approx[0][0][0],approx[0][0][1])
                 endpoint=(int((approx[3][0][0]+approx[4][0][0])/2),int((approx[3][0][1]+approx[4][0][1])/2))
                 slope=(startpoint[0]-endpoint[0])/(startpoint[1]-endpoint[1])
                 angle= math.degrees(math.atan(slope))
                 font= cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
                 cv2.putText(th1, str(angle), (10,85+50*ix), font, 1, (255,255,0))
                 print('angle=', angle)
             else:
                 pass**
    
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame= cap.read()
    blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5,5), 0)
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mi = cv2.getTrackbarPos("min", "Adjust")

    lower_red=np.array([0,100,100])
    upper_red=np.array([mi,255,255])
    mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red, upper_red)

    result= cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    ab,th1=cv2.threshold(result, 133,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    th1=cv2.erode(th1,None, iterations=2)
    th1=cv2.dilate(th1, None, iterations=2)

    getcontours(mask,th1)

    cv2.imshow('th1', th1)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    key= cv2.waitKey(500)
    
    if key== 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angle= math.degrees(math.atan2(startpoint[0]-endpoint[0], startpoint[1]-endpoint[1]))

#если нужен диапазон 0..360
if angle < 0:      
    angle +=  360
```

Я оставил отношение координат X/Y такое же, как у вас - видимо, оно для вашей координатной системы подходит. Для стандартной математической правой  СК  с горизонтальной осью ОХ должно быть `atan2(diff_y, diff_x)`

Comment: Мне выходит совсем не подходит то что я написал, но по другому не выходит. У меня задача чтобы камера следила за стрелкой спидометра (к примеру) чтобы слева получалось 0, вверху 90, справа 180 и т д.
Не могли бы вы объяснить как можно сделать так, как я описал выше?

Comment: `atan2(startpoint[1]-endpoint[1], startpoint[0]-endpoint[0])` нужные результаты даёт?

Comment: Совсем нет, слева нижняя четверть круга переходит из 72 в 287 (левая граница), вверху 300, справа 360 переходит в 0 и снизу 300.
</br>
При таком коде 

`startpoint= (approx[0][0][0],approx[0][0][1])
                 endpoint=(int((approx[3][0][0]+approx[4][0][0])/2),int((approx[3][0][1]+approx[4][0][1])/2))
                 slope= math.atan2(startpoint[1] - endpoint[1], startpoint[0] - endpoint[0])
                 angle= math.degrees(math.atan(slope))
                 if angle < 0:
                     angle += 360`

Comment: Блин, я же дал код для angle, зачем свой slope и atan сюда ещё притянули?

Comment: Если я правильно понял `angle= math.degrees(math.atan2(startpoint[1]-endpoint[1], startpoint[0]-endpoint[0]))`
По бокам 360, по серединам 270, честно говоря не понимаю

Comment: я ж не знаю, где у вас start и end. Если наоборот:  `atan2(endpoint[1]-startpoint[1], endpoint[0]-startpoint[0])`

Comment: Почти получилось, я вроде понял суть. Спасибо большое, очень помогли разобраться